# You can choose whichever of the two dates is more convenient for you

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence "You can choose whichever of the two dates is more convenient for you" accord to rules of grammar? I think there are two predicates. Am I right?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add to your question what you think the two predicates are? It would make the question and your thinking more complete and easier to reply to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example sentence sounds natural to my (American) ear.  Secretaries and receptionists often say things like this when booking appointments.

- Subject:  "You"
- Verb: "can choose"
- Object: "whichever of the two dates is more convenient for you"

The sentence could be re-written as:

- You can choose either of the two dates.

or

- You can choose the date that is more convenient for you.

Neither of these alternatives is as good as the original example, because each alternative leaves out important information.